# Openfire Users/Groups and Sessions admin area malfunctioning: "Domain cannot be null"

Tags: users, xmpp, openfire

I'm running Openfire 3.6.4 on a Debian Lenny (x86_64) system with about 40 concurrent users, which was installed via the .deb packet and ran fine for about a year. Then, some of my users complained about not being able to login  (the TLS connection was established, but then, no further XMPP communication happened). TLS is required for clients on my server. Still, most of the users could use the server normally, the problem constantly affected only small group of users.

I tried to restart the server with the provided /etc/init.d/openfire script. With restart and stop nothing happened, even after some retries and waiting for something to happen. Because of that I looked up the Java process ID and used kill (without any arguments but the process ID) to stop the server. It worked instantly. Afterwards I used the script to start the server again. The users could now use the server again, the problem seemed to have vanised.

Some days later I tried to create a new user via the web interface. I noticed, that the Users/Groups, Sessions and Connection Managers tab was inaccessible because of some strange exceptions which I will list below.

I have no idea what caused this or how to fix this. If you have any idea, please help me. This post was also posted on the forums of the Ignite Realtime Community.

Users/Groups

```
HTTP ERROR: 500

Domain cannot be null

RequestURI=/user-summary.jsp
Caused by:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Domain cannot be null
    at org.xmpp.packet.JID.(JID.java:261)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.SessionManager.getActiveSessionCount(SessionManager.java:905)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.spi.PresenceManagerImpl.isAvailable(PresenceManagerImpl.java:84)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.admin.user_002dsummary_jsp._jspService(user_002dsummary_jsp.java:254)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:97)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1093)
    at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter.parsePage(PageFilter.java:118)
    at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter.doFilter(PageFilter.java:52)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
    at org.jivesoftware.util.LocaleFilter.doFilter(LocaleFilter.java:66)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
    at org.jivesoftware.util.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:42)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
    at org.jivesoftware.admin.PluginFilter.doFilter(PluginFilter.java:70)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
    at org.jivesoftware.admin.AuthCheckFilter.doFilter(AuthCheckFilter.java:146)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:360)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:726)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:206)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:829)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:514)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)

Powered by Jetty://
```

Sessions

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Domain cannot be null
    at org.xmpp.packet.JID.(JID.java:261)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.SessionManager.isAnonymousRoute(SessionManager.java:659)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.admin.session_002dsummary_jsp._jspService(session_002dsummary_jsp.java:337)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:97)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1093)
    at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter.parsePage(PageFilter.java:118)
    at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter.doFilter(PageFilter.java:52)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
    at org.jivesoftware.util.LocaleFilter.doFilter(LocaleFilter.java:66)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
    at org.jivesoftware.util.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:42)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
    at org.jivesoftware.admin.PluginFilter.doFilter(PluginFilter.java:70)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
    at org.jivesoftware.admin.AuthCheckFilter.doFilter(AuthCheckFilter.java:146)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:360)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:726)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:206)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:829)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:514)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)
```

Server Settings -> Connection Managers

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.jivesoftware.openfire.multiplex.ConnectionMultiplexerManager
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.admin.connection_002dmanagers_002dsettings_jsp._jspService(connection_002dmanagers_002dsettings_jsp.java:149)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:97)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1093)
    at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter.parsePage(PageFilter.java:118)
    at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter.doFilter(PageFilter.java:52)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
    at org.jivesoftware.util.LocaleFilter.doFilter(LocaleFilter.java:66)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
    at org.jivesoftware.util.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:42)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
    at org.jivesoftware.admin.PluginFilter.doFilter(PluginFilter.java:70)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
    at org.jivesoftware.admin.AuthCheckFilter.doFilter(AuthCheckFilter.java:146)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:360)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:726)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:206)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:829)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:514)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved. The original process which denied some users to login seemed to have survived somehow. I killed all Openfire processes until they were really gone and restarted one. Now it works fine again.